# cancel button not displayed for wizard page created with wpInfoAfter in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have created a custom wizard page in inno, which needs to be shown after installing the files to {app} folder. This is achieved by giving the wpInfoAfter. 
The problem is, its showing only the 'next' button, there is no cancel/back button, also the dialog's closing button on top right is also disabled. I understand that the back button isn't needed, as it needs to remove the files which are installed. Is there anyway the 'cancel' button can be displayed?

Comment: The buttons are hidden as there is nothing to cancel. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Even the `Cancel` button itself is against that. Clicking it does exactly nothing since as @Deanna says, there's nothing to cancel when you've finished the installation process. Don't you rather make your own button to cancel some of your installation post process wizard (if you're going to do so) ?

Comment: The wizard is actually to get sql server details , and that it looks blank without any option to close, this force the user to enter correct details to move forward, as any wrong entries will not proceed further and they cant leave the field blank as well. Hence thought will have a cancel button. Please suggest.

Comment: Give them a skip option, or ask beforehand. The Cancel button in its usual place will imply that it's cancelling the whole setup.

Comment: So may be i will show a message box saying they have just cancelled this particular action and not the entire installation. should be ok?

Comment: @Deanna, I have now changed the plan, showing this page earlier and doing the executions later. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Cancel` button has no functionality at the after install stage, because InnoSetup doesn't expect to do further actions, that would require cancel, after the installation process is done. So, even if you show the button against that fact, you would get a button without any action.

Personally I would prefer to collect the information needed to setup your database before the installation starts, because consider the situation when the user installs your application and simply cancel the after installation wizard (what can easily happen). Doing it before, you'll be able to force your users to fill what you need before they actually get to the application itself. But if you still want to do it after install, here is a workaround for that missing cancel button.

As a workaround, you can create your own custom button, that will be on a same position with the same functionality. Here is a sample script, simulating a cancel button and showing it only on the custom page which is laying after the installation process. It's just a workaround, because you'd need at least fix this:

- enable the closing cross of the wizard form (it's disabled after the installation stage is done)
- handle the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key shortcut somehow (it invokes the exit prompt dialog too, but I couldn't find a way how to workaround this)

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
procedure ExitProcess(uExitCode: UINT);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

var
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;
  CancelButton: TNewButton;

procedure OnCancelButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // confirmation "Exit setup ?" message, if user accept, then... 
  if ExitSetupMsgBox then
  begin
    // stop and rollback actions you did from your after install
    // process and kill the setup process itself
    ExitProcess(0);
  end;  
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  // create a custom page
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpInfoAfter, 'Caption', 'Description');
  // create a cancel button, set its parent, hide it, setup the bounds
  // and caption by the original and assign the click event
  CancelButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  CancelButton.Parent := WizardForm;
  CancelButton.Visible := False;
  CancelButton.SetBounds(
    WizardForm.CancelButton.Left, 
    WizardForm.CancelButton.Top, 
    WizardForm.CancelButton.Width,
    WizardForm.CancelButton.Height
  );  
  CancelButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonCancel);  
  CancelButton.OnClick := @OnCancelButtonClick;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  // show your fake Cancel button only when you're on some of your after
  // install pages; if you have more pages use something like this
  // CancelButton.Visible := (CurPageID >= FirstPage.ID) and 
  //   (CurPageID <= LastPage.ID);
  // if you have just one page, use the following instead
  CancelButton.Visible := CurPageID = CustomPage.ID;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Tlama, however as suggested i revoked this plan, I am now showing this page much earlier and doing the executions later point of time. Thanks a lot.